# Particular exercise of Riemann integrable and compute integration

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, limsup-and-liminf, riemann-integration

Consider the function $f$ defined by

$f(x)=\left\{ \begin{array}{rcl}
0 & \mbox{for}
& x=\frac{1}{2}\mbox{ }\mbox{  or } \mbox{ }x=\frac{3}{2}\\ 
1 & \mbox{o.c.}
\end{array}\right.$

prove that $f(x)$ is integrable on $[0,2]$. Compute the integral.

***Proof.*** Let $\epsilon>0$. Set $\delta=min\{1/2,\epsilon/2\}$.

Then $P=\{0,\delta,2\}$

Then $U(f,P)=M_{1}(\delta)+M_{2}(1-\delta)$ and

$L(f,P)=m_{1}(\delta)+m_{2}(1-\delta)$.

Since $f(x)=0$ when $x=1/2 \mbox{ or } x=3/2$ and $f(x)=1 \mbox{ when } o.c.$

Then $M_{1}=M_{2}=m_{2}=1$ and $m_{1}=0$ (This is correct??)

Because if this correct Thus

$U(f,P)-L(f,P)=1(\delta) + 1(1-\delta)-0(\delta) - 1(1-\delta)$

$=\delta - \delta + 1 - 1 + \delta$

$=\delta$

$<\epsilon/2<\epsilon$

How can i prove that the integral of $f(x)=2$ to $[0,2]$??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any partition $P=\{x_{0},...,x_{n}\}$ of $[0,2]$, the supremum of $f$ on each subinterval $[x_{i-1},x_{i}]$, $i=1,...,n$ is no more than $1$, so $U(f,P)\leq\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_{i}-x_{i-1})=2$. Now on such subinterval $[x_{i-1},x_{i}]$, no matter if $1/2$ or $3/2$ lies inside, $f$ can always take the value $1$, so $U(f,P)\geq\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_{i}-x_{i-1})=2$, so the upper integral is $2$, since you have showed that it is integrable, the integral is equal to the upper integral.

Comment: Ok i have it, in my proof i mentioned that $M_{1}(f)=1$ and $M_{2}(f)=1$ but how could I justify this $m_{2}(f)=1$ correctly? or would you use a more refined partition? Which partition would you use?, regards

Comment: In particular, if $\epsilon=1/2$, $m_{1}=1$, $m_{2}=0$, so your argument will not work. By the way, you can choose the partition $[0,1/2-\delta]$, $[1/2-\delta,1/2+\delta]$, $[1/2+\delta, 3/2-\delta]$, $[3/2-\delta, 3/2+\delta]$, and $[3/2+\delta,2]$ with $\delta>0$ small enough that none of which overlap each other, draw a diagram might help.